# Xamarin Android google vision for android 10

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, computer-vision, google-vision

I am devoloping an app using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision. My problem is that I am able to run it/install on emulator (Android 9/10) but then I am unable to install it on my phone (Android 10). I was digging into this issue and it turns out that I cannot install my app because of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision package. When I try to install app it just shows: 'Application cannot be installed.'. It is strange because it worked on my emulator normally (with and without Google vision package). Does anybody has same experience??? Is there some way to solve this problem? Would it be better for me to just use different library?

My packages:
[image]

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:
My Logcat at the time of installing:

[08-28 14:25:58.148 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x75df2b3480

[08-28 14:25:58.171 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[LogcatLiveFragment] onServiceConnected

[08-28 14:25:58.350 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1

[08-28 14:25:58.350 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:25:58.350 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:25:58.354 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:25:58.355 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:25:58.355 25058:25058 V/InputMethodManager]
Starting input: tba=com.dp.logcatapp ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false

[08-28 14:25:58.355 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
startInputInner - Id : 0

[08-28 14:25:58.355 25058:25058 I/InputMethodManager]
startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

[08-28 14:25:59.941 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 0

[08-28 14:26:00.115 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 1

[08-28 14:26:00.620 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 0

[08-28 14:26:00.683 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 1

[08-28 14:26:03.451 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[Logcat] onActivityInBackground

[08-28 14:26:03.452 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1

[08-28 14:26:03.452 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:26:03.452 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:26:03.474 25058:25058 D/InputTransport]
Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=91

[08-28 14:26:03.778 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x75df2b3480 -> 0x0

[08-28 14:26:03.778 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
destroyEglSurface : 0x75df2b3480

[08-28 14:26:03.778 25058:25077 I/mali_egl]
eglDestroySurface() in

[08-28 14:26:03.781 25058:25077 I/mali_winsys]
delete_surface() [1080x2400] return

[08-28 14:26:03.781 25058:25077 I/mali_egl]
eglDestroySurface() out

[08-28 14:26:03.781 25058:25077 W/libEGL]
EGLNativeWindowType 0x766c1c7610 disconnect failed

[08-28 14:26:03.781 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
~ReliableSurface : 0x766c1c7600

[08-28 14:26:03.787 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=6 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true

[08-28 14:26:03.787 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
stopped(true) old=false

[08-28 14:26:03.797 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=4 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=false

[08-28 14:28:52.045 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x75df2b3480

[08-28 14:28:58.587 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[Logcat] onActivityInBackground

[08-28 14:28:58.591 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1

[08-28 14:28:58.591 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:28:58.591 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:28:58.610 25058:25058 D/InputTransport]
Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=77

[08-28 14:28:58.928 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x75df2b3480 -> 0x0

[08-28 14:28:58.928 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
destroyEglSurface : 0x75df2b3480

[08-28 14:28:58.928 25058:25077 I/mali_egl]
eglDestroySurface() in

[08-28 14:28:58.932 25058:25077 I/mali_winsys]
delete_surface() [1080x2400] return

[08-28 14:28:58.932 25058:25077 I/mali_egl]
eglDestroySurface() out

[08-28 14:28:58.933 25058:25077 W/libEGL]
EGLNativeWindowType 0x75559417d0 disconnect failed

[08-28 14:28:58.933 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
~ReliableSurface : 0x75559417c0

[08-28 14:28:58.938 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=5 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true

[08-28 14:28:58.938 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
stopped(true) old=false

[08-28 14:28:58.963 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=4 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=false

[08-28 14:29:16.795 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)4 dur=13 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false

[08-28 14:29:16.796 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
stopped(false) old=true

[08-28 14:29:16.807 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
stopped(false) old=false

[08-28 14:29:16.808 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[Logcat] onActivityInForeground

[08-28 14:29:16.808 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[Logcat] Posting pending logs

[08-28 14:29:16.821 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=7 res=0x7 s={true 508620337152} ch=true

[08-28 14:29:16.822 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
createReliableSurface : 0x75559417c0(0x766c227000)

[08-28 14:29:16.823 25058:25077 I/mali_winsys]
new_window_surface() [1080x2400] return: 0x3000

[08-28 14:29:16.827 25058:25077 D/OpenGLRenderer]
makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x75df2b3480

[08-28 14:29:16.845 25058:25058 D/LogcatReader]
[LogcatLiveFragment] onServiceConnected

[08-28 14:29:16.848 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1

[08-28 14:29:16.848 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:29:16.848 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:29:16.850 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@48556d3[MainActivity]

[08-28 14:29:16.850 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
getNavigationBarColor() -855310

[08-28 14:29:16.850 25058:25058 V/InputMethodManager]
Starting input: tba=com.dp.logcatapp ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false

[08-28 14:29:16.850 25058:25058 D/InputMethodManager]
startInputInner - Id : 0

[08-28 14:29:16.850 25058:25058 I/InputMethodManager]
startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

[08-28 14:29:17.864 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 0

[08-28 14:29:18.062 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 1

[08-28 14:29:19.934 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 0

[08-28 14:29:20.011 25058:25058 D/ViewRootImpl@6e2fd9d[MainActivity]]
ViewPostIme pointer 1

Comment: What is reported in `logcat` when you `adb install xxx.apk` it?

Comment: Hello. I cannot show logcat today, sorry. I will edit my answear in 10-20 hours as I cannot acess the device rn.

Comment: Please create a new project, install same nuget packages, then install it in your android device. If it works.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my inactivity. I have tried creating new project and then installing it. it worked. Then I added GooglePlayService.Vision package and archived it same as before. Then it could not be installed. I am 100% possitive that this package is problem.

Comment: Hello, again, I added logcat. I am new to making mobile apps so please tell me if it has some info that will help. Again I dont know how to read these things,... So sorry if I did someting wrong..